# "HV000183 - EL dependencies not found" using hibernate-validator 7.0.0.Final / jakarta.el 4.0.1

Tags: hibernate-validator

I've a kotlin spring boot project with `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:7.0.0.Final` and `org.glassfish:jakarta.el:4.0.1`.

For testing validation constraints I create a `javax.validation.Validator`, like so:

```
val factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
validator = factory.validator
```

This results in the following error: `HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use  ParameterMessageInterpolator instead`. Which I find strange, since I included them per the instructions: https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/

If I combine `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:7.0.0.Final` and `org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.0` it works, but it looks like `7.0.0.Final` should not be used with `javax.el`, but with `jakarta.el`, without me knowing the reason why at the moment: https://in.relation.to/2021/01/06/hibernate-validator-700-62-final-released/

Any ideas on what I need to do to use `hibernate-validator` v7?